# Kaa - Issue with Raspberry Pi example app

Tags: kaa

I am attempting to follow this tutorial: http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Raspberry+Pi

When I run the final commands:

```
tar -zxf notification_demo.tar.gz
cd CppNotificationDemo/
./build.sh deploy
```

After it finishes building it displays:

> Press Enter to subscribe to optional topics

I press Enter, then it displays:

> Press Enter to exit

I do not press Enter, and after a couple minutes this error message shows up

> [client_1][2017-Jan-19 11:29:22.287762][0x755ff450][warning][HttpClient.cpp:41]:Transport error occurred: Connection timed out
>   [client_1][2017-Jan-19 11:29:22.313916][0x755ff450][warning][AbstractHttpChannel.cpp:103]:    Channel [default_bootstrap_channel] failed to connect 130.113.109.160:9889: Connection timed out
>   [client_1][2017-Jan-19 11:29:22.353513][0x755ff450][warning][AbstractHttpChannel.cpp:124]:    Channel [default_bootstrap_channel] detected 'CURRENT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER_NA' failover for TransportConnectionInfo{ server: 'BOOTSTRAP', protocol: 'TransportProtocolId{ id: 0xfb9a3cf0, version: 1 }', accessPointId: -1835393002, isFailed: 'false' }
>   [client_1][2017-Jan-19 11:29:22.354396][0x755ff450][warning][KaaChannelManager.cpp:157]:    No Bootstrap services are accessible for TransportProtocolId{ id: 0xfb9a3cf0, version: 1 }. Processing failover...
>   [client_1][2017-Jan-19 11:29:22.355018][0x755ff450][warning][KaaChannelManager.cpp:148]:    Attempt to reconnect to first Bootstrap service will be made in 5 seconds

What does this error message mean, and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That message usually means the application cannot connect to the Kaa Sandbox. There might be several issues with that and you should try all of them until it start working.

1. Ensure you run the application from the same PC host the Kaa Sandbox is running. In this case, with the default Sandbox configuration the application should be able to normally access all the necessary Kaa services located on the Kaa Sandbox with no additional configuration.
2. If you need to run the application remotely (i.e. from another host PC and the Kaa Sandbox virtual machine is accessible through the local network), you need to change the Kaa host configuration on the Administration UI, Manage page to the real IP address of the PC host the Kaa Sandbox is running on. Then, you will need to re-generate Kaa SDK, download it and use during the application build.
3. If neither of this works for you, the network and (or) other configuration is incorrect and need investigation. Please describe your network topology, all the PC hosts involved, what steps did you go after downloading of the Kaa Sandbox and how did you build the application. We will analyse this data and try identify the issue root cause.